# ErrorBoundary does not work with react-router swith

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I Added an ErrorBoundary to display a fallback UI when an unexpected error occurs in my react app.

Once an error occurs, the error message will continue to be displayed on any route I move to.

Image: 
https://doc-0s-2k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/4ch1l011b8g7qko9upr3tjelpnc5cjsp/m8r10j4c6gnfjbrdkioqeaq92rj8v7tp/1567065600000/04643321946847820866/04643321946847820866/1G5a7prXBQ4FHBXPNMeGaTH5WbzXLhrIk?e=view

I'm using:

- react-16.8.6
- react-router-dom-5.0.0

https://github.com/ichironagata/react-error-boundary

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    <PublicRoute exact path="/" component={Top} />
    <PublicRoute exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
    <PublicRoute exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      }
    />
  );
};
```

```
export const Page2 = () => {
  throw new Error('Page2 crashed');

  return (
    <div>
      Page2
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What  error occurs? Please post it

Comment: There is no error message. The behavior is weird. Please look at this **gif**.

Comment: The link of the image is not working. Please provide an image.

Comment: @JojoTutor I have the same issue, but I have a working demo of the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056211/why-does-using-an-error-boundary-disable-routing-when-the-routes-are-inside-of-a