# Error Boundaries disables routing inside of a Switch

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-router

For [a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658813/why-does-routing-stop-working-even-when-using-an-errorboundary) I have been trying to get routing to work in our app after an error boundary has been hit, but only today did I find the code that was seemingly identical to the many examples lying around had one important difference: the routes were wrapped by a `Switch`. This simple change is enough to stop routing from working, if enabled. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-boundaries-working-with-a-router-im420)

Take the following snippet. If I remove the `Switch` bit, this works fine even if each component should fail, but not if wrapped by the switch. I would like to know why.

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc993", height: "150px" }}>
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/"
    exact
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <MyComponent1 title="Component 1" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/comp1"
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <MyComponent1 title="Component 1 Again" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/comp2"
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <MyComponent2 title="Component 2" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, this problem boils down to how React does [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#component-elements-of-the-same-type).

> When a component updates, the instance stays the same, so that state is maintained across renders. React updates the props of the underlying component instance to match the new element

Say we have this example app:

```
<App>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="a" component={Foo}/>
    <Route path="b" component={Foo}/>
  </Switch>
</App>
```

This will, somewhat unintuitively, reuse the same instance of `Foo` for both routes! A `<Switch>` will always return the first matched element, so basically when React renders  this is equivalent of the tree `<App><Foo/></App>` for path "a" and `<App><Foo/></App>` for path "b". If Foo is a component with state, that means that state is kept, as the instance is just passed new props (for which there are none, except `children`, in our case), and is expected to handle this by recomputing its own state.

As our error boundary is being reused, while it has state that has no way of changing, it will never re-render the new children of its parent route.

React has one trick hidden up its sleeve for this, which I have only seen explicitly documented on its blog:

> In order to reset the value when moving to a different item (as in our password manager scenario), we can use the special React attribute called key. When a key changes, React will *create a new component instance rather than update the current one*. 
>   (...) In most cases, this is the best way to handle state that needs to be reset.

I was first hinted to this by a somewhat [related issue on Brian Vaughn's error bondary package](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary/issues/23#issuecomment-425470511):

> The way I would recommend resetting this error boundary (if you really want to blow away the error) would be to just clear it out using a new key value. (...) This will tell React to throw out the previous instance (with its error state) and replace it with a new instance.

The alternative to using `key`s would be to implement either exposing some hook that could be called externally or by trying to inspect the `children` property for change, which is hard. Something like this could work ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-boundaries-working-with-switch-1s07r)):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    const childNow = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    const childPrev = React.Children.only(prevProps.children);

    if (childNow !== childPrev) {
        this.setState({ errorInfo: null });
   }
```

But it's more work and much more error prone, so why bother: just stick to adding a `key` prop :-)

Answer (score 4):

To give you the shortcut of this fix, please see the new **"key" prop** on each of the ErrorBoundary component and each must be unique, so the code should look like this:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/"
    exact
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary key="1">
        <MyComponent1 title="Component 1" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/comp1"
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary key="2">
        <MyComponent1 title="Component 1 Again" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/comp2"
    render={() => (
      <ErrorBoundary key="3">
        <MyComponent2 title="Component 2" />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )}
  />
</Switch>
```

To elaborate, the answer of @oligofren is correct. Those 3 ErrorBoundary components are the same instances but may differ in props. You can verify this by passing "id" prop to each of the ErrorBoundary components.

Now you mentioned why is that if you remove **Switch** component, it works as expected? Because of this code:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/e81dfa2d01937969ee3f9b1f33c9ddd319f9e091/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L40

I recommend you to read the official documentation of **React.cloneElement** here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

I hope this gives you an idea on this issue. Credit to @oligofren as he explained in more details about the idea of the instances of those components.

Comment: I am not totally sure what additional knowledge I am supposed to understand from the links :-) The `Switch` source code just returns (a clone of) the first match. It does change the matched node _slightly_ using cloneElement, but only by adding some extra props { location, computedMatch: match } from the router to give the component access to the Router props. How does that effect this situation? Just trying to understand better :-)